# How to go about customizing UIButton

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, model-view-controller, uibutton, objective-c-category

I'm trying to customize my buttons by using a category but I don't want all my buttons in my project to use this category. Is there a way to let the button know it should/shouldn't use the category (Like some sort of bool isUsingCategory). If not, whats the best way to go about this? I would subclass it but I hear that subclasssing UIButton is a bad idea. Is there a way to exclude categories from certain objects? Thanks!

EDIT: What I have right now that's working is in my controller running a special method to draw the buttons but I don't think thats follows MVC very well.

Comment: If you are just customizing appearance, you could use the `appearance` proxy. But unfortunately this will affect all UIButton objects. The best way to differentiate _is_ to subclass. Why is that supposed to be bad?

Comment: Ooooh I thought of another way. Make a custom UIView subclass. Let's call it MyButtonContainer. Make all buttons that you want to customize subviews of a MyButtonContainer, which is itself can be invisible (clear) so it affects nothing. Now the `appearance` proxy has a way to pick out the right buttons.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202161/why-shouldnt-i-subclass-a-uibutton

Comment: Well that's utter bosh (as one of the comments rightly says). If you subclass UIButton, it won't be a UISystemButton. But it will be a UICustomButton, and what on earth is wrong with that?

Comment: No need to worry about all instances using a category.  The category just adds methods where 'self' is understood to be an instance of the class being extended.  Not calling those methods is equal to not using the category.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to **inherit from the UIButton** (for example MyButton) and **add one property** something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL useCategoryBehavior;
```

In the category of MyButton **use this property before do something** in overriden methods. Like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (useCategoryBehavior) {
        // do smth here
    }
}
```