# Cannot set UIButton buttonType in initializer in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to subclass a UIButton in Swift. I get an error when setting `buttonType`

```
class MyButton: UIButton {

    init(label: KeyLabelType) {

        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)

        self.buttonType = UIButtonType.Custom
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on why this is incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The apple docs say that `buttonType` is a readonly property. You will have to find a workaround for this. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202161/why-shouldnt-i-subclass-a-uibutton) might give you what you are looking for.