# UIButton subclass not responding to super methods?

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton, uicontrol, uicontrolevents

I would like to create a UIButton that toggles its image. Once clicked the image should change to another one and stay that way until clicked again.

I have added both images to the default and selected states of the button on interface builder.

Now, I have created a UIButton subclass. My idea is to intercept the tap to that button and change the button state. So I added this to the UIButton subclass, hoping one of these methods would be triggered by a tap.

```
- (void)sendAction:(SEL)action
                to:(id)target
          forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

  [super sendAction:action to:target forEvent:event];

  // toggle state
  [self setSelected:![self isSelected]];

}


- (void)sendActionsForControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents {
  [super sendActionsForControlEvents:controlEvents];

  // toggle state
  [self setSelected:![self isSelected]];

}


- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches
           withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

  [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
  // toggle state
  [self setSelected:![self isSelected]];
}
```

None of these methods are triggered. Any clues?

Comment: Is button hooked up to one of these in IB & is it set to the subclass in identity inspector?

Comment: Maybe you should try a different approach, check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202161/why-shouldnt-i-subclass-a-uibutton)

Comment: what do you mean? The button was added on interface builder and an action was set there, by dragging to the class it is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be barking up the wrong tree (pun partially intended), but I created a Swift project that does what I think you're asking for. I realize you're using ObjC, but for sake of time on my part I made it in Swift. In any case, it'll give you somewhere to start.

Here is the repo on GitHub: [Click Here](https://github.com/kbpontius/ButtonExample)

--> Note: You'll need >= Xcode 6 to run the project.

A few things to note in the project:

1 - Be sure and connect the Button on `Main.storyboard` to the class you've created.

2 - In Swift, the `class MyButton: UIButton` is the line that implements `UIButton` for the class. I'm certain there's an ObjC equivalent, this Stack Overflow question may be helpful syntactically: [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500327/subclass-uibutton-to-add-a-property)

Hopefully some of this is helpful!

Good luck,

Kyle

Comment: Thanks. I just recreated everything and it is now working. It must be one of those Xcode issues.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the first two aren't called because the button doesn't have any `target`s registered with `selector`s.  The third not being called is a little surprising.

That being said, you should to try `[self addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventsTouchUpInside]`.

Comment: the action is being set on interface builder. Surprisingly, if I add a breakpoint to the action, I see this on the thread: `[UIApplication sendAction:to:forEvent:]`, that in theory is the first method I have added.

Answer (score -1):

The only way this can happen is if you haven't called `addTarget` on the UIButton subclass.

Comment: what do you mean? The action is set on interface builder.