# Swift UIButton override, setImage is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibutton, uiimage

I'm trying to subclass `UIButton` with my own button class called `FlipsSendButton`. The code for this class is listed below. In it you can see that I am calling `setImage` to attempt to set the button image. However, after compiling, everything works correctly EXCEPT setting the image view.

Am I missing some steps in my code to set the image, or perhaps calling the optional and unwrap operators incorrectly?

```
import Foundation

class FlipSendButton : UIButton {

    let bgColor : UIColor

    init(frame aFrame: CGRect, bgColor aColor: UIColor) {
        bgColor = aColor;

        super.init(frame: aFrame)

        addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonTouched:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        backgroundColor = aColor;

        setImage(UIImage(named: "flips.png") as UIImage?, forState: .Normal)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        bgColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func buttonTouched(sender: UIButton) {
        if backgroundColor == UIColor.lightGrayColor() {
            backgroundColor = bgColor
        } else {
            backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        }
    }
}
```

Also, it is worth mentioning that the image flips.png is in my images.xassets folder, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forgot the `buttonType` property. Besides, you'd better not subclass the `UIButton`(check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202161/why-shouldnt-i-subclass-a-uibutton) for the reason).

Instead, You should set the `buttonType` property to `UIButtonTypeCustom` when you init the button, some sample code:

```
var myButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(.UIButtonTypeCustom)
myButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "flips.png") as UIImage?, forState: .Normal)

myButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("buttonTouched:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

func buttonTouched(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.backgroundColor == UIColor.lightGrayColor() {
        sender.backgroundColor = bgColor
    } else {
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    }
}
```

-- EDIT --

If you want to reuse the style configuration, a better way is to define your own **factory method** of `UIButton`. Something like:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import ObjectiveC

private var bgColorKey: UInt8 = 0

extension UIButton {

    var bgColor: UIColor {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &bgColorKey) as! UIColor
        }
        set (neewColor) {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &bgColorKey, neewColor, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        }
    }

    class func buttonWithFrame(f: CGRect, backgroundColor color: UIColor) -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
        button.frame = f
        button.backgroundColor = color;
        button.bgColor = color
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "flips.png") as UIImage?, forState: .Normal)
        button.addTarget(button, action: "buttonTouched:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        return button
    }

    func buttonTouched(sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.backgroundColor == UIColor.lightGrayColor() {
            sender.backgroundColor = sender.bgColor
        } else {
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use the button like:

```
var btn = UIButton.buttonWithFrame(CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 50), backgroundColor: UIColor.greenColor())
self.view.addSubview(btn)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I get the following error: Cannot assign to buttonType in self.

Comment: Gotcha. That is what I finding out, but was hoping I could get around it (since I already coded the thing). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @NoahLabhart I edited my answer and added a workaround with that you needn't change your code a lot but has the same result. see it please. Perhaps the most appropriate way :)

Comment: Thanks, this looks good.  I think this would work, but I reverted to UIImageViews. If those don't work, I will be backing up and trying this out.

Comment: Thanks, your answer made me realize: As long as "someone else" sets the image, it works.
So i tried a different approach with setting the UIButton's image from an inline class (see answer below)

Comment: this part helped me. myButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "flips.png") as UIImage?, forState: .Normal). thank you

Answer (score 2):

I found this frustrating as well. A fully functional UIButton subclass, that it's only flaw is `setImage:`. 
The easier solution I've found is writing a tiny helper class to set the image from outside:

```
class ButtonImageHelper {

    func setImage(image: UIImage?, forButton:UIButton) {
            forButton.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }   
}
```

This class can be positioned inside your UIButton subclass.
To call it:
`ButtonImageHelper().setImage(yourImage, forButton:self)`