# How to prevent from clipping the subviews when I set the cornerRadius of a UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cornerradius, cliptobounds

I am trying to set the cornerRadius of a subclass view of UIButton, the round corner shows in a right way, but when I try to add a subView(the flower icon) on it, the subview seems to be clipped like the picture on the **right** side below, this is not what I expected. I try to make the correct appearance like the picture shows on the left side, the icon not be clipped. The code I use:

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.width / 2;
button.layer.masksToBounds = Yes;
```

[image: Avatar View(left)]
[image: Avatar View(right)]

Hope someone can help me to understand how to prevent from clipping.
Thanks!

Comment: You SHOULD NOT subclass UIButton class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202161/why-shouldnt-i-subclass-a-uibutton

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't add the overlay as a subview then. Subviews will be clipped if you set `clipsToBounds` to `YES`.

Instead add it as a sibling, like so:

```
- container view
  - image view (clips)
  - overlay view
```

Comment: Thanks! But in this case,  this avatar view is a subclass of UIButton, the avatar is set by some URL using some complex logic, so if I need to refactor it, it will have a lot of work to do...

Answer (score 0):

If you are making the button rounded using your above mentioned code then your button will definitely get chopped from the corners so if you only want to chop it from 3 corners then do this:

```
#import <QuartzCore/CoreAnimation.h>

UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:button.bounds 
                                           byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight | UIRectCornerBottomLeft
                                                 cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(7.0, 7.0)];
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = button.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
button.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Comment: Thanks! It's a quick solution, but... the designer reject it because the appearance is not what he expected :-(

Comment: no problem. You can ask your designer what exactly he/she wants..may be i can help.

Comment: As the picture shows, I mean the picture on the left side in the question, that is what the designer expect...