# Equivalent to UIButtonTypeRoundedRect in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit

When I try to use `UIButtonType` in swift, UIButtonTypeRoundedRect no longer exists:

[image]

Is there an equivalent in Swift, or do I need to make a new subclass to get the same look?

Comment: I can't imagine this is *actually* Swift specific.  I'm pretty sure that button type was deprecated in iOS7.

Comment: Right you are sir - it turns out it's not Swift specific, I just happened upon it during a swift migration for an app. #hattip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not in SDK included within Xcode 6.4:

```
enum UIButtonType : Int {

    case Custom // no button type
    @availability(iOS, introduced=7.0)
    case System // standard system button

    case DetailDisclosure
    case InfoLight
    case InfoDark
    case ContactAdd
}
```

But in SDK included in Xcode 7, it's back and marked as deprecated.

```
enum UIButtonType : Int {

    case Custom // no button type
    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    case System // standard system button

    case DetailDisclosure
    case InfoLight
    case InfoDark
    case ContactAdd

    static var RoundedRect: UIButtonType { get } // Deprecated, use UIButtonTypeSystem instead
}
```

You should use `System`. If it doesn't fit your needs, do not subclass `UIButton`, use custom factory method [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13202244/581190).

Answer (score 2):

Just use a plain button and cut your own corners:

```
let button = UIButton()
button.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
button.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `UIButtonTypeSystem` instead.

[image]

[UIButton Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIButtonType)