# How to reuse properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, properties, label

I have many different buttons in my app, yet most of them have the same properties assigned to them:

```
login = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, CGRectGetMaxY(password.frame) + 16, loginView.frame.size.width - 16, 40)];
[login setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[login.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir Next" size:18]];
[login setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[login setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.7 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[login setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

Is there any way to create a class or something of a button that already has these default properties assigned? So I could simply go something like:

```
CustomButtom *btn = [CustomButton alloc]init];
```

Then the `btn` will have all of the above properties assigned?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating a  **CustomButton** class

Xcode -> **New File** -> **Cocoa Touch Class** -> **Next** -> Name Your Button-> Select **Subclass** of **UIButton**

CustomButton.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomButton : UIButton

@end
```

CustomButton.m file

```
#import "CustomButton.h"

@implementation CustomButton


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
// Drawing code
//login = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, CGRectGetMaxY(password.frame) + 16, loginView.frame.size.width - 16, 40)];
[self setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir Next" size:18]];
[self setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.7 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
}

@end
```

Now, Call you button

```
CustomButton *customButton = [[CustomButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, CGRectGetMaxY(password.frame) + 16, loginView.frame.size.width - 16, 40)];
[customButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loginButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[YourView addSubview:customButton];
```

Comment: It's not advised to subclass UIButton: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202161/why-shouldnt-i-subclass-a-uibutton

Comment: Also for the love of all that is holy, don't change the button state in `drawRect` unless you want your app to be unresponsive every time it draws the button

Answer (score 2):

Another way of handling this, is you can create a private method that will return the UIButton with the same properties. I think creating a subclass of UIButton is a little unnecessary.

Comment: I would love some example code from your answer, as it sounds superior?

Answer (score 0):

You've got two options:

- Make a function that you can pass in a `UIButton` to that sets the properties for you
- Write a Category for UIButton that does the same as the above. Categories allow you to add functionality to a class without subclassing. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can subclass the UIButton. When you override the init method setting the properties you could get the button's with the same properties.