# How to show view controller from custom UIButton class?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, uiview-hierarchy

I have following view hierarchy: navigation controller, inside it I pushed another view controller which contains UITableView with custom UIButtons in the cells. I have another view controller (MyCustomViewController2), which I want to show above all this stuff with animation.

But I am confused with this hierarchy and I don't know how to overwrite `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method in my custom UIButton class. The code that I've come so far is:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    MyCustomViewController2 *myVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyVC"];
    [self.window addSubview: myVC.view];
}
```

But it's so bad! And I don't have any animations and I should delete it to remove. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

[It's highly recommended not to subclass a UIButton.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202161/why-shouldnt-i-subclass-a-uibutton) So I wouldn't.

But since UIButton is a subclass of UIControl, you can use this method directly:

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target
           action:(SEL)action
 forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
```

Example in code could look like this:

```
[self.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showOtherVC) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This will look at the target *(self)* for a particular method *(showOtherVC)* when the user lifts their finger from the button.

You could then have the current View Controller present the new one modally using this UIViewController method as example:

```
-(void)showOtherVC
{
     MyCustomViewController2 *myVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyVC"];
    [self presentViewController:myVC animated:true completion:nil];
}
```

Read more on UIControl here: 
[UIControl Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/)

And check out other UIViewController modal transition styles here:
[UIViewController Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/)