# How to override UIButton's init with button type in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, overriding

I want to subclass `UIButton` and add to it a property `isActive`, which is a `Bool` that changes the look of the button (this is not related to the default `.enabled` property).

However, I also want to set the button type when initialized. Specifically, I want to initialize it much like it is in `UIButton`, like:

```
let button = MyButton(type: .Custom)
```

However, because the `.buttonType` is a read-only, I cannot just override it like:

```
convenience init(type buttonType: UIButtonType) {
    buttonType = buttonType
    self.init()
}
```

This spits out an error: `Cannot assign to value: 'buttonType' is a 'let' constant` (I already implemented the required `init(coder:)`).

So how can I set the `.buttonType` when initialized?

---

NOTE: The custom property shall be also used in other functions to change the logic within it, so I picked up a property, instead of defining two functions to change the look.

Comment: `buttonType = buttonType`  does that make sense in swift?

Comment: Try `self.buttonType = buttonType`

Comment: @Chris It got the same result.

Comment: @Blaszard Different button types are represented by different (private) subclasses of UIButton. That's why you can only set type at creation time but not after. What exactly do you want to do? Can you explain it to us thoroughly? I am smelling [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Comment: @ozgur I want to subclass `UIButton` and initialize it using `init(type:)` initializer.

Comment: Maybe this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202161/why-shouldnt-i-subclass-a-uibutton

Answer (score 0):

You don't need use it, according to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624028-init):

> This method is a convenience constructor for creating button objects with specific configurations. If you subclass UIButton, this method does not return an instance of your subclass. If you want to create an instance of a specific subclass, you must alloc/init the button directly.
>
> When creating a custom button—that is a button with the type UIButton.ButtonType.custom—the frame of the button is set to (0, 0, 0, 0) initially. Before adding the button to your interface, you should update the frame to a more appropriate value.

means button you created already custom, just use init()

Answer (score -10):

buttonType is read-only, so you have to set the type via UIButton's  convenience initializer:

```
convenience init(type buttonType: UIButtonType) {
    self.init(type: buttonType)
    // assign your custom property
}
```

Comment: Nope. Endless loop.