# How do I create a growing iOS Button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uibutton

My friend gave me the following designs for iOS buttons, and I'm not sure the best way to implement this.

**I need to make the reusable button shown below (in Objective-C).**

I've tried:

- Subclassing the button, but read that I [shouldn't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202161/why-shouldnt-i-subclass-a-uibutton)
- Animating the border (while subclassed), but the border only goes inwards, so it seems like I need to animate the frame too

So how do I approach this? I'm assuming making a CustomButtonView class which has a button (composition) as well as an inner and outer circle view? How would I then animate that to grow? Would I have to animate the frame change too, or could I use insets?

What is the simplest code to make this work? Thanks!

[image: Growing Buttons]

Comment: have you tried setting your button.clipToBounds = false. This will allow your border to grow past the bounds of the button and not only inwards

Comment: That would only work on subviews, so it doesn't work on a button subclass, correct?

Comment: No, it should work on the button subclass as well. Anything that inherits the UIView class can call clipsToBounds. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here Is the approach I took to create this:

[image: ButtonAnimation]

1. Subclass UIView to create your custom button
2. Use `UITapGestureRecognizer` or `touchesBegan`, `touchesEnded`... for your interaction
3. Add two `CALayer`'s for your foreground and background layers
4. Add your icon layer (This can be an UIImageView or any other way of displaying an image)

   ```
   - (id)initWithIcon:(UIImage *)icon backgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor foregroundColor:(UIColor *)foregroundColor {

       if (self = [super init]) {
           // Background Layer Setup
           _backgroundLayer = [CALayer new];
           [_backgroundLayer setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor.CGColor];
           [self.layer addSublayer:_backgroundLayer];

           // Foreground Layer Setup
           _foregroundLayer = [CALayer new];
           [_foregroundLayer setBackgroundColor:foregroundColor.CGColor];
           [self.layer addSublayer:_foregroundLayer];

           // Icon Setup
           _icon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:icon];
           [_icon setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
           [self addSubview:_icon];

           UIGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:)];
           [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
       }
       return self;
   }

   - (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {

       // Make sure super is called
       [super setFrame:frame];

       // Build the layout of backgroundLayer
       [self.backgroundLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(frame.size.width*0.1, frame.size.width*0.1, frame.size.width*0.8, frame.size.width*0.8)];
       [self.backgroundLayer setCornerRadius:frame.size.width*0.8/2];

       // Build the layout of forgroundLayer
       [self.foregroundLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(frame.size.width*0.05, frame.size.width*0.05, frame.size.width*0.9, frame.size.width*0.9)];
       [self.foregroundLayer setCornerRadius:frame.size.width*0.9/2];

       // Build the frame of your icon
       [self.icon setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.width)];
   }

   - (void)buttonTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gesture {

       // Animate the foreground getting smaller
       CABasicAnimation *foregroundFrameChange = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"frame"];
       foregroundFrameChange.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:_foregroundLayer.frame];
       foregroundFrameChange.toValue   = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width*0.1,self.frame.size.width*0.1, self.frame.size.width*0.8, self.frame.size.width*0.8)];
       self.foregroundLayer.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width*0.1,self.frame.size.width*0.1, self.frame.size.width*0.8, self.frame.size.width*0.8);

       // Animate the forground cornerRadius to stay rounded
       CABasicAnimation *foregroundRadiusChange = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"cornerRadius"];
       foregroundRadiusChange.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.foregroundLayer.cornerRadius];
       foregroundRadiusChange.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.frame.size.width*0.8/2];
       [self.foregroundLayer setCornerRadius:self.frame.size.width*0.8/2];

       // Animate the background getting larger
       CABasicAnimation *backgroundFrameChange = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"frame"];
       backgroundFrameChange.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:self.backgroundLayer.frame];
       backgroundFrameChange.toValue   = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.width)];
       self.backgroundLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.width);

       // Animate the background cornerRadius to stay rounded
       CABasicAnimation *backgroundRadiusChange = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"cornerRadius"];
       backgroundRadiusChange.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.backgroundLayer.cornerRadius];
       backgroundRadiusChange.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.frame.size.width/2];
       [self.backgroundLayer setCornerRadius:self.frame.size.width/2];

       // Group all the animations to run simultaneously
       CAAnimationGroup *allAnimations = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
       allAnimations.duration   = 2;
       allAnimations.animations = @[foregroundFrameChange, foregroundRadiusChange, backgroundFrameChange, backgroundRadiusChange];
       allAnimations.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
       [self.layer addAnimation:allAnimations forKey:@"animate"];

       // Create your button action callback here
   }
   ```

   This was a quick mock up and not a complete solution but it will give you something to play with.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This really helped me understand how to put it all together, and it's working now, so thank you :D